# Salesforce Open Popup via Trigger

Tags: trigger, php, popup

I am creating lead using Force.com Toolkit for PHP.

I have also created trigger when any lead is created. using this trigger I wants to open one popup or model in salesforce screen. is it possible ?

Comment: Triggers can't perform any UI actions Ashwin. Those are for deal with any logic whenever a database transaction occurs.

Comment: Then is there any possibility to open popup using create apex page and map with trigger?

Answer (score 3):

After the lead is inserted via the API you can retrieve the resulting record Id. This is after all the triggers have completed and control has returned to your PHP code.

Then in your PHP code you can redirect the user to a new URL that includes the resulting lead ID.

The URL will be something like:

> https://na5.salesforce.com/00Q300000000001

You will want to pull the server url from the toolkit based on the connection. I think this is the `$location` or `endpoint` in the `SforceBaseClient`. The `00Q` part will be the new Lead ID. If the user doesn't already have an active session in the browser you can either set a cookie for them out bounce the request through a login URL.

---

**Disclaimer: I've never written a line of PHP before.** This might work, or it might not compile (Is PHP compiled or interpreted?). This was partially butchered from the [Workbench source for jumpToSfdc.php](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/forceworkbench/blob/master/workbench/jumpToSfdc.php).

```
// Get the Lead Id from the inserted record. Assumes only one. Not error checking...
$response = $mySforceConnection->insert($leadRecords);
$leadId = $response[0]->id;

// Split the location URL to get the Salesforce domain.
preg_match("@((https?://)((.*)-api)?(.*))/services@", 
    $mySforceConnection->getLocation();, $sfdcApiHost);

// [1] => https://na4-api.salesforce.com
// [2] => https://
// [3] => na4-api
// [4] => na4
// [5] => .salesforce.com

if ($sfdcApiHost[3] != null) {
    //special cases
    switch ($sfdcApiHost[4]) {
        case "na0": $sfdcApiHost[4] = "ssl"; break;
        case "ap0": $sfdcApiHost[4] = "ap"; break;
        case "eu0": $sfdcApiHost[4] = "emea"; break;
    }
    $sfdcUiHost = $sfdcApiHost[2] . $sfdcApiHost[4] . $sfdcApiHost[5];
} else {
    $sfdcUiHost = $sfdcApiHost[1];
}

$jumpUrl = "$sfdcUiHost/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=". $mySforceConnection->getSessionId() 
            . "&retURL=%2F" . $leadId;

// Redirect the browser to the frontdoor to login to Salesforce and navigate to the lead.
header("Location: " . $jumpUrl);
```

Comment: Hi Denial,
Thanks For update. I hope this will work but can you please give example of Force.com Toolkit for PHP. So it can be very useful for me.

Comment: I tried setEndpoint($location) function but it is not open that location in salesforce. Please suggest.

Comment: Actually I am using Force.com Toolkit for PHP to insert lead (REST API). when any rest api call and lead is created after that I wants to open popup or model in salesforce who ever is login in salesforce. 

So here salesforce screen is open in another window and lead api call is in another window. I wants to open popup when any lead successfully created then wants to open popup in salesforce screen.

Please suggest.

Comment: I've put something together that will hopefully point you in the right direction. It will redirect the browser to the lead that was inserted. You may need to adapt it open a separate browser window.

Comment: Hi Danial, 

Thanks for update, I have tried this but there is some confusion over here. My scenario is different. I have account callportal like twillio and when call start I am calling salesforce api and create lead into salesforce. but at a same time in my screen only open salesforce account. I wants to open popup in salesforce screen when any lead is created. Please suggest ?

Comment: @Salesforce Rather than using `header()` to redirect the browser window you will need to use Javascript to create the popup window for $jumpUrl. Use `window.open()` from Javascript with the value of $jumpUrl as the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks for answered. But this is not solution for my issue. Issue is something diefferent. I am having marchex (call portal) account. this call portal is provide call start and callback url facilities to post call data to set url.

When I call to someone at that time automated entry into marchex. and marchex portal is redirect that call data which I have set into call start url. 

**(continue in next msg)**

Comment: The callstart url set let's say xyz.com on this server I have written code for create a lead for call data using force.com toolkit php.

In agent side, Agent are only logged in salesforce account. now when marchex (call portal) redirect to xyz.com and when create a lead into salesforce at that time agent screen will show popup which with msg "lead is created".